# smbus write block vs multiple write byte

Tags: i2c

I can't find any good documentation for the `python-smbus` package recommended to communicate over I2C on Raspberry Pi. I see there are [several write commands](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-python/i2c-programming-in-python/using-the-i2c-interface-2) including `write_byte_data` and `write_block_data`. Is `write_block_data` practically different from several `write_byte_data`?

Eg, are these equivalent?

```
bus.write_block_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, (0x05, 0x12, 0xff))
```

```
bus.write_byte_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, 0x05)
bus.write_byte_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, 0x12)
bus.write_byte_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, 0xff)
```

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67364/read-data-from-si7021-via-i2c The question there is phrased around a specific sensor but the underlying issue is the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
bus.write_block_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, (0x05, 0x12, 0xff))
```

The above is a single bus transaction.

```
bus.write_byte_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, 0x05)
bus.write_byte_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, 0x12)
bus.write_byte_data(ADDRESS, REGISTER, 0xff)
```

The above is three distinct bus transactions.

As well as the overhead of three separate transactions you need to take into account how the I2C device defines its protocol.  Depending on the device those two examples might have the same or different results.  **There is no one rule, you have to check each device datasheet**.

Comment: In general, one had also take care of not creating unneccessary stop conditions as another bus master may take over after a stop. That's something missing in most I²C libraries as multimaster setups aren't common.